# C# to VB.NET Framework 4 parallel programming

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

I've been strugling to convert this piece of code to vb.net for a while now and none of the code conversion engines online converts it correctly. Please help.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch watch;
        watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        //serial implementation
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Do stuff
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Serial Time: " + watch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString());

        //parallel implementation
        watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Do stuff with i
        }
        );
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Parallel Time: " + watch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the converter struggling? If this is all the code you need to translate, why not do it by hand?

Comment: With the System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For loop... I'm not familiar with c# and i'm unable to fnd a vb.net example.

Comment: here you have example on parralel for in both c# and vb, maybe helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx#Y0

Comment: @T.Vorster: Why not have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784105.aspx)? It has examples of both the **C#** and the **VB.NET** version of `Parallel.For`

Comment: I wasn't even aware that VB.NET offers a console application template.  There isn't anything C# specific to be honest.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the vb.net version of that `Parallel.For`:

```vb
Parallel.For(0, 10, 
       Sub(i)
           Thread.Sleep(1000)
           '--Do stuff with i
       End Sub)
```